# jquery_1.default is not a function webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I want to use external import jquery of webpack, but when I use `import $ from 'jquery'` the browser throws the error `jquery_1.default is not a function`, and after I changed the import syntax to `import * as $ from 'jquery'` and `const $ = require('jquery')`, it's still the same.
I used typescript and webpack and vue. Who knows what I should do? Thanks in advance.

tsconfig.js
[image]

webpack.config.js
[image]

The error information
[image]

globals.d.ts
[image]

Comment: By declaring `jquery` as an external in the webpack configuration, you are saying that you will load it into the target environment another way.  How are you loading it?  `<script src=...>`?

Comment: Just like this `import jquery from 'jquery'`,  it is not loading?  There is a jquery in my node_modules.

Comment: If you want webpack to include the jquery from your node_modules in the main bundle (which I assume you are loading somehow), then you shouldn't declare `jquery` as an external.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  In fact, I don't declare jquery in `.d.ts` files, it's still make a mistake

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Have you tried removing `jquery` from the `externals` section of the webpack configuration?  What happens then?

Comment: yes, I have removed `jquery` from `externals`, and I used `script` import `jquery`.Now, There is no error. Thank you so much. My english is very low.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a better approach than that described in your question. If you install jquery and @types/jquery via npm and then import it in controllers only where used, you will not need jquery configuration or declaration in neither webpack.config.js nor globals.d.ts.

1. Remove jquery externals configuration from webpack.config.js
2. Remove all `var jquery = require("jquery");` and `declare var jQuery: any;` instances from code
3. Run `npm install jquery --save`
4. Run `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`
5. Add `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to any controllers where needed

You can then do:

```
if (!$.trim(this.inputName)) { 
    console.log('inputName was empty or whitespace only');
} else {
    console.log('inputName contained alphanumeric text');
}
```

Always use `$` to reference the library instead of `jquery` hereafter.